# How to put a line on top of text in html?

Tags: html, css

So I want to try to do this in html and css but I can't seem to find anything. I only way I can think is by importing the text as an image but that will look bad.

> P.S Light blue line is for centering as I am designing the site in
> Photoshop first

[image: What I want to do in html and css]

```css
.test {
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">
  Conact Me
</p>
```

Comment: Provide your code  please

Comment: Just put a border on top of the text

Answer (score 15):

A simple solution is using `text-decoration: underline overline`.

```css
p {
  text-decoration: overline underline;
}
```

```html
<p>CONTACT ME</p>
```

Comment: Would that be responsive or would I have to add extra things to make it responsive? (Am new to web development)

Comment: @Cmi What do you mean by responsive?

Comment: Like when it's on a different device screen

Comment: @Cmi Do you want this to look different on different screen sizes? If so, how?

Comment: It's okay I will try to figure that part out, thanks for the help. But would overline and underline be supported on all browsers. I never heard of overline it's why am asking.

Answer (score 4):

You can use border-top in css to create a line above text.

```
.mytextbox {
    border-top: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

[border-top property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-top.asp)

[Example of use](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyOyBM)

Comment: Try `display: inline-block;`. This will make the width as long as the text is.

Comment: After that you can adjust the padding-left and padding-right properties to get it the way you want it.

Comment: I added an example to demonstrate.

Comment: @Leo is there a way for me to say put like an icon in the middle of the line?

Comment: I updated my example to show you how to do it using css ::after selector. Just swap out the text for the element you want to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try using borders to achieve the look you are wanting:

```
a.my-class {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd want to have the text element within a div, set the bg color property of the div to the color you're going for, and then set margins for the text element to push off the text by ~10px or so (looks like that's about where it's at in your mock up). From there you can set a border to only top, and bottom and style accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text inside a block level element and apply a [top and bottom border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border). Advantage of this method against the `text-decoration: underline overline;` is, that you can simply define the space between text and lines with `padding` as you need it.

To make the width as long as the text is, just use `display: inline-block;`.

```css
body {
  background: #5cc8f6;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>Contact me</div>
```